# Saving a spark dataframe in multiple parts without repartitioning

Tags: sql, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I want to query my database and store only the top 1 million records sorted by some column say column1.
I have tried two approaches

1. I load parquet files into a dataframe from the HDFS and apply SQL Query to it and then I save the the complete dataframe(10 million records) as text files on HDFS.

   ```
   df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table order by column1")
   df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("<path>")
   ```

   I then read the text files and fetch 1 million records from the text file.
2. I limit the SQL query to 1 million records.

   ```
   df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM table order by column1 LIMIT 1000000")
   df.rdd.saveAsTextFile("<path>")
   ```

   But the second approach is much slower. I found that in second case dataframe returned by SQL query(df) contains only 1 partition and thus it is written in a single task. Repartitioning the dataframe improved the performance in second case but it was still slower than first case.

Please can anybody suggest an approach to save the dataframe faster in case 2 or any other approach to achieve the same task

Comment: Not sure if it makes a difference, but `df.write.text(<path>)` seems more idiomatic, and maybe respect partitioning better ?

Comment: So your goal is to simply select top N values by some column? Do you need N to be exact? What is the type of column1?

Comment: How did you read the parquet files from HDFS exactly ?

Comment: Using dataframe API to read parquet files

Comment: No the query is complicated but finally after applying the query I want top N values sorted by a column containing int type entries

Comment: @ C4stor `df.write.text(<path>)` only supports writing single column tables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `column1` is numeric one possible solution is to estimate distribution and `filter` instead of sort and `limit`. Assuming your data looks like this:

```py
from pyspark.mllib.random import RandomRDDs

df = RandomRDDs.normalRDD(sc, 1000000, 10, 323).map(lambda x: (x, )).toDF(["x"])
```

and you want to take 100 top records:

```py
n = 1000 # Number of records to take, lets say 1000
```

you can estimate fraction of records you have to take:

```py
q = 100 * (1 - n / float(df.count()))
```

estimate respective quantile:

```py
import numpy as np
from pyspark.sql.functions import col


threshold = np.percentile(
    df.sample(False, 0.05).select("x").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect(),
    [q]
)[0]

result = df.where(col("x") > threshold)
result.write.format(...).save(...)
```

This doesn't shuffle at all and keeps initial record distribution but doesn't guarantee exact number of records and requires additional action with related network IO.

Comment: Isn't this same as df.limit(1000) which returns a dataframe with top 1000 records? The problem is picking top 1000 records out of the dataframe results in a loss of partitioning of the dataframe

Comment: It is not. It doesn't shuffle the data at all but it has to collect a sample.