# order by in spark is very slow

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm writing a query that need "order by col1,col2,col3"
it took 600 sec and this order by was the cause.
I do believe it's required shuffle, but is there a replacement or any optimization idea to do ?

````
  val rankQuery = s"select x_label,y_label,x,y From ($Xquery) order By  x_label,y_label,y" ```
````

then I do the

```
    sqlSession.sql(rankQuery).rdd
    .zipWithIndex().map(t => t._1 + "--" +t._2).map(f=>{
     val values = f.split("]")(0).split("--")(0)
     val indx = f.split("--")(1).toLong.+(1)
     val x_label = values.split(",")(0).substring(1)
     val y_label = values.split(",")(1)
     val x = values.split(",")(2)
     val y =  values.split(",")(3)
     (x_label,y_label,x,y,indx)
   }).toDF
```

to add indexes and calculate the rank.
Xquery is just doing concatination

Comment: very slow for how much data? 10 records? 10 billion? shuffling is almost unavoidable.

Comment: this might help although you are using Spark SQL https://stackoverflow.com/q/38619121/2096986